# Fatal Error C1083 While using sparsehash library

Tags: c++, fatal-error

Hi I am using google sparsehash library. When i compile the code (Visual Studio 2005)it gives following error...
    **fatal error C1083**: Cannot open include file: 'sparsehash/sparse_hash_map': No such file or directory

What is the reason behind this problem and what is its solution.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: isn't the error self explanatory enough?

Comment: Either you don't have the file mentioned our you haven't told your compiler where to find it.

Comment: I have placed the source code of google hashmap library in the project hierrarchy tree but it is still giving the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you installed https://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/ and your makefile correctly updated to include header file from this sparsehash i.e. something like

-I ./sparsehash/include

In case of Visual Studio make sure your project setting refer to path where file is located.

Comment: Thanks alot Saqlain. There is a zip file containing code stuff, on the link you mentioned above. How to install it.

Comment: Iam Using Visual Studio 2005

Comment: extract it there will be a file README_windows.txt just follow its instructions, and make sure to include required header files present in sparsehash in your VS project settings, in case you need help on how to include header files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702302/how-to-include-header-files-in-visual-studio-2008